# 'Newest questions' without on-hold or duplicate filter?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, search

When browsing the newest questions on movies.Stackexchange I tend to see and find tons of questions that are put either '**on-hold**' or are marked as '**duplicate question**'.

This might be on other SE's also but is there a way to **filter those out**?
I have no intention of viewing duplicated posts or questions that are already put on hold due to lack of information or the post isn't related to the SE.
Can I browse the newest questions without seeing the questions that are put on-hold or marked as duplicate? If not could this be a feature-request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For things like this you can use the very feature-rich and nicely documented search features that every SE site has. If you visit the [search page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search) (for example by typing in something in the search box in the top right) you see a little expandable box called "Advanced Search Tips" on the right site. This lists many neat search command you can employ to specificy your search further, for even more information you can also consult the [respective page in the help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

One of those options is `closed:yes/no`, which will show/hide all question that are closed or on hold for any reason, including duplicates. If you want to hide/show duplicates explicitly, there is also `duplicate:yes/no`. So to find all the newest questions that have not been closed or marked as duplicate you would just [search for `closed:no` and order the results by "newest"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ano).